Design of LCL Filter with wide power range
I'm following the TI guide for a 10KW grid-tied AFE (Active Front End Inverter), Link. My questions are, what happens to the system when running at a much lower power, say 100W instead of 10KW? Will the LCL filter designed for 10KW still be effective and stable at 100W? If not, what needs to be implemented to get it working under wide load conditions?  How can I go about determining the minimum power?


Please expand your acronyms!

Have you tried using a simulator to get your answer?

Understand the concept of invariants:
To scale a design to another nominal power level but keeping voltage the same, reduce currents proportionally.  Transistors will be proportionally smaller, impedances higher, inductances higher, and capacitors smaller.
Or to change the cutoff frequency (to change the output ripple, or vary proportionate with a change in Fsw), make L and C proportionally smaller for Fc higher.
It's not clear if you want an inverter rated for 100W, or to operate a 10kW inverter at 100W.  In the latter case, there is no change, and losses will simply be high compared to output, as the transistor capacitance and filter losses remain present.
